# Encrypting a string in Cyrillic using XOR

Tags: java

I want to encrypt the string with XOR. The source text is in Cyrillic. After encrypting, I get the hieroglyphs, how can I fix it? I'll use the UTF-8 encoding.

```
String text = "Какой-нибудь русский текст"; // some cyrillic text
String sKey = LFSR(); // return string "10011010" for example

System.out.println("[PSP]: key: " + sKey); // output: 10011010

byte[] txt = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
byte[] key = sKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

byte[] res = new byte[txt.length];

for (int i = 0; i < txt.length; ++i) {
    res[i] = (byte) (txt[i] ^ key[i % key.length]);
}

try {
    System.out.println(new String(res, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); 
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

ފ���������������������������������������

I think it's because the byte values are negative.

Comment: Why do you expect readable text from xorred bytes? What are you hoping to see?

Comment: @Kayaman, Because when encrypting an English word, for example, the output values are correct, they are a set of English letters. I expect to see a Cyrillic character set

Comment: Then your "encryption" is very shifty. You can't expect the ciphertext to be in readable letters unless you use a simple substitution cipher like [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher). XOR maps bytes to bytes, so the ciphertext should be unreadable, no matter what the language.